# PHP Script Cycle Through Stores

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4, development, script

I have a php script I use to update an attribute. I have it set on ADMIN store at the moment, however I need it to update for each store that does not have default values set.

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

How do I change this to either run for all stores, or get it to cycle through each store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone finding this and wondering how I resolved code is below

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$storeCollection = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection();
foreach($storeCollection as $store)
{

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeid);


$products_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                                                         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                                        ->addStoreFilter($storeid);

foreach($products_collection as $product)
{
```

As much as it this may not be the most efficient way it did resolve my issue